# What does the tag "goldfish" mean?

Tags: discussion

A user with solid reputation on this site (over 1500 rep) tagged [a question of mine](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/6626/how-fast-can-you-win-against-a-passive-opponent-in-the-innistrad-block-format) with the "goldfish" tag. What does that mean? The question obviously has no connection to a real goldfish, but I don't get the deeper meaning behind this tag. Anyone able to share light on this?

Comment: sorry about probably not providing enough information in the "reasons for edit", so that you could see why the tag was editted. Ire&Curses has it right, a goldfish is a helpless opponent that does nothing to prevent you from playing your deck (what you described in the question). Goldfishing is sometimes  used to see how fast a deck can win(win on average).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From this [list of Magic:The Gathering jargon](http://www.wizards.com/Magic/Magazine/Article.aspx?x=mtgcom/academy/9):

> *Goldfish* - Playing a deck against no opposition to see how it draws
>   and how quickly it can win, given no resistance. At one point, this
>   also referred to playing a deck against an imaginary opponent who
>   simply cast a 2/2 for two every turn, though that usage has fallen out
>   of favor.

I've added this description to the [goldfish](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/goldfish) tag wiki. I don't have an opinion on the tag one way or another.